# Doubt in Example 4.3.4 of Brémaud's Markov Chains book

Tags: markov-chains, steady-state

I'm reading Brémaud's Markov Chains, Gibbs Fields, Monte Carlo Simulation and Queues 2nd edition and I'm not following example 4.3.4 in page 159. Here's what's in it:

> Let $A$ be a square matrix of dimension $r$ with $r$ distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1 , \dots , \lambda_r$, and let $u_1 , \dots , u_r$ be the associated left eigenvectors and
> $v_1 , \dots , v_r$ be the associated right eigenvectors. Then both the systems  $u_1 , \dots , u_r$ and $v_1 , \dots , v_r$ are linearly independent.
> Moreover, $u^T_i v_j =0$ if $i \neq j$,and we can choose them in a way that $u^T_i v_i =1$ for each $1\leq i \leq r$, in which case we have the spectral decomposition:
> \begin{equation}
> A^n = \sum_{i=1}^r \lambda^n_i v_i u^T_i.
> \end{equation}

> Example 4.3.4: The transition matrix on $E=\{1,2\}$,
> $$
> P=\begin{bmatrix}
> 1-\alpha & \alpha\\
> \beta & 1-\beta
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> where $\alpha,\beta \in (0,1)$ has for characteristic polynomial $(1-\alpha-\lambda)(1-\beta-\lambda)-\alpha\beta$, which admits the roots $\lambda_1 =1$ and $\lambda_2 = 1-\alpha-\beta$. The right eigenvector associated with $\lambda_1 =1$ is $v=\mathbf{1}$, with all entries equal to $1$. Also, the stationary distribution
> $$
> \pi^T = \left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} , \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}\right)
> $$
> is the left eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $1$.
> In this example, the spectral decomposition takes the form:
> $$
> P^n =\frac{1}{\alpha + \beta} \begin{bmatrix}
> 1-\alpha & \alpha \\
> \beta & 1-\beta 
> \end{bmatrix} + \frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)^n}{\alpha + \beta} \begin{bmatrix}
> \alpha & -\alpha \\
> 1-\beta & -\beta 
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
> and therefore, since $|1-\alpha-\beta|<1$,
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} P^n = \frac{1}{\alpha + \beta} \begin{bmatrix}
> 1-\alpha & \alpha \\
> \beta & 1-\beta 
> \end{bmatrix}.
> $$
> In particular, the result of convergence to steady state,
> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} {P}^n = \mathbf{1} \pi^T
> $$
> was recovered for this special case in a purely algebraic way.

If I understood correctly, by the last line of the example we should have:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} {P}^n = \mathbf{1} \pi^T = \frac{1}{\alpha + \beta}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} \beta & \alpha \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{\alpha + \beta}\begin{bmatrix} \beta & \alpha\\  \beta & \alpha\end{bmatrix},
$$
but this obviously doesn't coincide with the expression in the 3rd to last line:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P^n = \frac{1}{\alpha + \beta} \begin{bmatrix}
1-\alpha & \alpha \\
\beta & 1-\beta 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Also, I've done the calculations myself and the spectral decomposition I got is:
$$
P^n = \frac{1}{\alpha+\beta}\begin{pmatrix}{\beta} & {\alpha}\\{\beta} & {\alpha}
\end{pmatrix} +\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)^n}{\alpha+\beta}\begin{pmatrix}{\alpha} & -{\alpha}\\-{\beta} & {\beta}\end{pmatrix}
$$
which, taking limit when $n \to \infty$, coincides with $\mathbf{1} \pi^T$. Are the spectral decomposition and the equation in the 3rd to last line of the example wrong?

Comment: @user619894 thanks, edited

Comment: I took some random values in $[0,1]$ for $\alpha,\beta$ and checked in a little python program that your formulas must be correct and Bremaud's 3rd to last line therefore must be wrong.

Comment: @KurtG. ok, thanks for checking!